# How do I receive input to store as a string in a winforms project in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, input

I'm working on a program that asks for input, then calculates and posts the output.

I managed to do it on a console application, but I don't know how to store input from a textbox.

The input has to be positive integers, with an error message in place if anything invalid is input (to prevent crashing).

I plan to have use a button to trigger the calculation and output, but I need to know how to store the input first.

Comment: There's a lot of tutorial on the web, just use google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a click handler to your button with double-clicking on it. afterwards, insert the following code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string text = textBox1.Text;
}
```

the text from the textbox is now within variable text.

Answer (score 1):

Double click your button to add a handler method, then grab the value from the field as an integer:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int foo;
    int bar;
    if ( ! Int32.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out foo))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Foo must be a number!");
        return;
    }
    if ( ! Int32.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out bar))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Bar must be a number!");
        return;
    }
    // do something with foo and bar
}
```

Comment: I have multiple text boxes. How can I use this for all of them?

Comment: @Slateboard, I updated my answer to show two fields: textBox1 and textBox2.

Comment: It worked. It doesn't crash when an invalid value is input. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Store the input in instance variables. I believe that the information is stored in a property of the textfields. Something along the lines of

```
 theNameOfYourTextField.text
```